# fread() on binary file for integer gives wrong value

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, binaryfiles, fread

I am trying to read 2 integers off a binary file before reading the rest into a matrix. In the original text file, it shows:

```
4  4
6 0 -6 -3
0 -4 0 1
-6 0 -2 -3
-3 1 -3 -5
```

then converted to binary using "hexdump [file] > test":

```
0000000 2034 3420 360a 3020 2d20 2036 332d 300a
0000010 2d20 2034 2030 0a31 362d 3020 2d20 2032
0000020 332d 2d0a 2033 2031 332d 2d20 0a35
000002e
```

My problem is when i write:

```
foo(int *nrows, int *ncols){
...
file = fopen(filename, "rb");
if(NULL == file){
                        *nrows = 0;
                        *ncols = 0;
                }
                else{
                        fread(nrows, sizeof(int), 1, file);
                        fread(ncols, sizeof(int), 1, file);
                        printf("nrows : %d\n", *nrows);                                                                                                                                                       }
...
}
```

Instead of nrows or ncols reading 4, it reads 808464432.

How do I get it to read the correct integer, or at least be able to convert this to the correct integer for comparison purposes? I would need to be able to read a binary file, so I cannot switch to fscanf as far as I can tell.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that's a binary file?

Comment: Your "converted" file is still a text file.

Comment: Doing a hex-dump of a text file just gives you the same file, represented as hexadecimal digit pairs, rather than ascii characters. Assuming you're using a little endian architechture, I'd expect the first 8 bytes of the file to look more like this: 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 - That's 2, 4 byte integers that each hold 4. ;)

Comment: Thanks. How do I properly make a .bin file then?

Comment: What about a program that has an array with all your values in it. You then simply step through the array, putting each element into a 4byte integer, before using `fwrite(&tmpInteger, sizeof(int), 1, fileHandle);` to write to an already opened file.